# Calculating if Lat Long is within a country using C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am curious if it is possible to work out what country we are in based on Lat/Long.
If for this purpose Germany, France and Belgium are square and we have the corner lat/long for each of the countries, how can we work out of the lat/long that is queried with is within one of these countries.

For example, [Google Maps JS API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) have the ability to set the LatLongBounds and query if anything is in it.
Is there anything like it for C# or am I overlooking something?

Thank you for your time,

Qwan

Comment: Is application a webs or a desktop application? Can you assume that your user will always have a working Internet connection?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154593/country-code-from-a-latitude-longitude-position-without-using-geocoding-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across this little ditty the other day while looking into feasible solutions for this problem myself. Why rebuild the wheel when someone already has a great solution with a tremendous amount of data?

[This](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#countrysubdiv) web service will return the iso country code based on lat/long.

Comment: +1 This looks quick and simple if all you are after is the country.

Comment: Thank you, currently this is exactly what I am after.
Will be looking into geocoding further as well mind so thanks @Ranhiru Cooray aswell.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Reverse Geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)

Comment: +1, beat me to it. Google API is def. the way to go, and they can provide both XML/JSON return objects, which are fully acceptable within C#/.NET.

Comment: @Brad Christie I actually disagree, ESRI rules the GIS world. You CAN use the Google API, but I find you can do much more with ESRI API's.

Answer (score 1):

Another reverse geocoding service [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/export/reverse-geocoding.html)