# Get the country name from Latitude and Longitude-No Google

Tags: geolocation, gis

Can I get the country information just from `Latitude` and `Longitude` of the user? I know it should be easy to get it from `Geocoder` APIs from Google. But is it possible to derive that information without using any services like Google's?

Could you please let me know?

Comment: Duplicate of **[Country code from a latitude longitude position (without using geocoding services)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154593/country-code-from-a-latitude-longitude-position-without-using-geocoding-service)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way of doing this is by using a third party API or creating your own database, which is a lot more work that it's worth. Have you looked to see if there is a GeoIP database that you can download for your programming language of choice (Or a generic one?)

Edit: [This looks like it might have the data you need](http://earth-info.nga.mil/gns/html/namefiles.htm)

Comment: We have to do that using JavaScript and Application cache.Size limit is a concern in our case.